# Android JSON parse multiple objects

Tags: android, json, gson

I have JSON as such:

```
{
  "Temperature": {
    "Name": "Temperature",
    "Value": "26.19",
    "Unit": "C"
  },
  "Humidity": {
    "Name": "Humidity",
    "Value": "29.38%",
    "Unit": "%"
  }
}
```

and I want to save it into List of objects of same type. Here is my class:

```
public class Measurement {
    private String name;
    private String value;
    private String unit;

    public Measurement(String name, String value, String unit){
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String getUnit() {
        return unit;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return name + " = " + value + unit;
    }
}
```

I have tried it usng gson like this:

```
Type measurementListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Measurement>>(){}.getType();

List<Measurement> msm = new Gson().fromJson(json, measurementListType);
```

but that gives error

> Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Provided JSON is just an example, it could have any number of objects, but they would all have to follow same structure. How can I parse them into List? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that JSON you're showing to be an array of objects, it needs to be sorrounded by square brackets, like this:

```
[{
    "Temperature": {
        "Name": "Temperature",
        "Value": "26.19",
        "Unit": "C"
    },
    "Humidity": {
        "Name": "Humidity",
        "Value": "29.38%",
        "Unit": "%"
    }
}]
```

From there you can have one or multiple objects inside the array.

Comment: So I changed JSON format to [
  {
        "Name": "Temperature",
        "Value": "26.19",
        "Unit": "C"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Humidity",
        "Value": "29.38%",
        "Unit": "%"
    }
] and it worked. I will accept your answer as it helped me understand what was wrong. Thank you.